# Angular directive to stop default click event

Tags: angular

The use case is, using Angular, create a directive that can be used to stop the default (click) event if a condition is true. If false, allow that default (click) event to fire.

All the code below works, except it does NOT stop propagation, so the click event handler on the button is still firing.

HTML

```
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [myDisabled]="reactiveForm.invalid" (click)="onSubmit()">A11y Disabled</button>
```

Typescript directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Renderer2, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[myDisabled]',
})
export class A11yDisabled {

private _isdisabled: boolean = false

constructor(
    private _elementRef: ElementRef,
    private _renderer: Renderer2
){}

@Input() set edjDisabled(condition: boolean) {
    console.log('condition', condition);
    if (condition) {
        this._isdisabled = true;
        this._renderer.addClass(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'a11y-disabled');
        this._renderer.setAttribute(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'aria-disabled', 'true');
    } else {
        this._isdisabled = false;
        this._renderer.removeClass(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'a11y-disabled');
        this._renderer.removeAttribute(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'aria-disabled');
    }
}


@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
onClick(e: any) {
    console.log('mouseup', this._isdisabled);
    if (this._isdisabled) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('stop', this._isdisabled);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using click event preventDefault you can use css `pointer-event:none` to disable all click

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  Renderer2,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myDisabled]'
})
export class A11yDisabled {
  private _isdisabled: boolean = false;
  @Input() set edjDisabled(condition: boolean) {
    console.log('condition', condition);
    if (condition) {
      this._isdisabled = true;
      this._renderer.addClass(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'a11y-disabled');
      this._renderer.setAttribute(
        this._elementRef.nativeElement,
        'aria-disabled',
        'true'
      );
    } else {
      this._isdisabled = false;
      this._renderer.removeClass(
        this._elementRef.nativeElement,
        'a11y-disabled'
      );
      this._renderer.removeAttribute(
        this._elementRef.nativeElement,
        'aria-disabled'
      );
    }
  }
  @HostBinding('style.pointerEvents') get pE() {
    return this._isdisabled ? 'none' : '';
  }

  @HostBinding('tabindex') get tabIndex() {
    return this._isdisabled ? '-1' : '';
  }

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) {}
}
```

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8yhvk2?file=src/app/button-overview-example.ts)**